# Adding content style to an element using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick

I have the following HTML label:

```
<div class="VINDesc">
    <input class="toggle-box" id="toggle" onclick="sendVinCustomLink()">
    <label class="VINDesc-label" for="toggle">foo?</label>
    <p>NEW TEXT.</p>
</div
```

The label's `css` is the following:

```
.toggle-box + label:after {
    background-color: #3b434a;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    content: "+";
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 12px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0px 2px;
}
```

My question is how do I add this style for when I click on it:

```
.toggle-box:checked + label:after {
    content: "\2212";
}
```

Everything I tried so far doesn't update the element. I am trying to make the `+` sign turn into a `-` on a click.

I added functionality to the sendVinCustomLink() function but it doesn't seem to update the label's appropriate `css`.

Any idea how this can be done?

**EDIT #1:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/shsfY.jpg

Comment: @Ouroborus sorry I had the wrong HTML there. `type="checkbox"` is not in the element. Without it the +/- symbol doesn't change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**:

One way to do this is to declare content as a var in your CSS like this:

```
content:var(--content,"+");
```

Then target and change the content like this:

```
div.style.setProperty("--content", "'-'")
```

**Additionally**, to answer your other question in comments about toggling the content to its previous "+" state. Simply apply a `boolean` that you can change for each click like this:

```
var bool = false;

  if (bool === false) {
    div.style.setProperty("--content", "'-'")
    bool = true;
  } else if (bool === true) {
    div.style.setProperty("--content", "'+'")
    bool = false;
  }
```

With the above code we are effectively changing the content string based on the boolean we declared as `bool`. When `true` we see `+` and when `false` we see `-`.

See the snippet below:

```js
var div = document.querySelector('.toggle-box + label');
var bool = false;

function changer() {
  if (bool === false) {
    div.style.setProperty("--content", "'-'")
    bool = true;
  } else if (bool === true) {
    div.style.setProperty("--content", "'+'")
    bool = false;
  }
}
```

```css
.toggle-box+label:after {
  background-color: #3b434a;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  content: var(--content, "+");
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 12px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="VINDesc">
  <input class="toggle-box" id="toggle" onclick="changer()">
  <label class="VINDesc-label" for="toggle">foo?</label>
  <p>NEW TEXT.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am trying to make the `+` sign turn into a `-` on a click.

Comment: Also I made a mistake in my original post, there is no `type="checkbox"`. I removed it from the question.

Comment: hmm I keep getting a `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null at changer at HTMLInputElement.onclick` error when I click on the label.

Comment: Are you running this script from a separate JS file? If so, make sure it's being called before the closing body tag in your HTML. - If you can provide your function I can help you with the issue, however, with the error you mentioned it seems that either your element doesn't exist, you're declaring it improperly, or your script is running before the DOM has loaded.

Comment: I just removed the whole file and just added your snippet. Added images to main question (edit #1).

Comment: Move the entire script before your closing `</body>` tag. Right now it's right before the `</head>` tag and running before the DOM has loaded. If you move it, it should work.

Comment: This fixed it! Any idea how to make it toggle though? Rotating between `+` and `-`? Right now it is staying on `-` after the first click.

Comment: There are a few ways, the most simple for this code is adding a boolean that you can change for each click. See the updated snippet above. When you click the input more than once it will change the content back and forth based on the true/false bool. Please remember to mark correct ✔️ if this has solved your issue.

Comment: You are a legend.